# Even though "ayn shliach l'dvar aveirah" does the person who sent him also get a punishment?

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, reward-punishment, torts-damages, shlichus-agency

The *Mishnah* in [Bava Kamma 59a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.59b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) tells us that if Reuven sent a חרש שוטה וקטן (a person who does not understand the repercussions  of his actions or under Bar Mitzva) to do a destructive action e.g handing him burning coals which he uses to destroy a field  Reuven would be:

> "פטור בדיני אדם וחייב בדיני שמים"
>   exempt in a human court, but liable in the court of Heaven.

However if Reuven sent Shimon to do a destructive act (Shimon understands what he is doing and is over Bar mitzva), Shimon would be *chayav*.

The Gemara in [Kiddushin 42b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.42b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) referencing this *Mishnah* asks:.
 Why isn't Reuven liable surely"שלוחו של אדם כמותו" ( Shimon is doing his bidding and represents Reuven)!
Then answers

> "שאני התם דאין שליח לדבר עבירה דאמרינן דברי הרב ודברי תלמיד דברי מי שומעים"
>   i.e a person's agent is like himself doesnt apply for an *aveirah*, because when there is a conflict between the words of *Hashem* vs human being, we should obviously follow *divrei Hashem*

**My question:** I understand that the Shimon is *chayav* (liable) for the action for the reason mentioned above - but is Reuven completely off the hook scott-free? Would he possibly get a "פטור בדיני אדם וחייב בדיני שמים" in this case as well, even though it's not a חרש שוטה וקטן? Or some other form of penalty/ punishment?

(e.g: In American law, if someone enlisted a murder-for-hire person both would be punished- not just the one who committed the action)

Comment: perhaps it would fall under the category of "Lifnei Iver"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one persuades someone to kill someone else we know that there is punishment from G-d similar to one that actively kills someone else as Dovid was blamed for killing Uria by sending him to the front lines even though he did't physically kill him as it says in the Gemora Kiddushin:

> האומר לשלוחו צא הרוג את הנפש הוא חייב ושולחיו פטור שמאי הזקן אומר משום חגי הנביא שולחיו חייב שנא' (שמואל ב יב, ט) אותו הרגת בחרב בני עמון מאי טעמיה דשמאי הזקן קסבר שני כתובים הבאים כאחד מלמדין והוא ההוא לא דריש ואיבעית אימא לעולם דריש ומאי חייב חייב בדיני שמים מכלל דת"ק סבר אפילו מדיני שמים נמי פטור אלא דינא רבה ודינא זוטא איכא בינייהו

The Rambam Hilchos Rotzeach 2,2 paskens such a case is liable to Misa bidei Shamayim which is death executed by Heaven:

> אבל [א] השוכר הורג להרוג את חבירו או ששלח עבדיו והרגוהו. או שכפתו והניחו לפני הארי וכיוצא בו והרגתהו חיה וכן ההורג את עצמו. כל אחד מאלו שופך דמים הוא. ועון הריגה בידו וחייב מיתה לשמים

With regards to other Aveiros if the person is unaware of the severity of his actions i'd imagine the prohibition of "Lifnei Iver" would apply to the inciter, as the Sifra Vayikra 19,14

> "ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול"-- לפני סומא בדבר. בא אמר לך "בת איש פלוני מה היא לכהונה?" אל תאמר לו כשרה והיא אינה אלא פסולה.

The punishment for Lifnei Iver is from Heaven as there is no Malkus (lashes) from Beis din Shel Mato. Chinuch:

> ואין לוקין עליו לפי שאין בו מעשה

Of course a person shouldn't preach others to do sins even if they know what they're doing so I'd imagine there is punishment from Heaven although probably not punishment of death like Preaching to worship idols see Rambam Mitzva Lav 15: לא להדיח בני ישראל לעבוד עבודה זרה

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough and thoughtful response!